What is the Wumpa fruit amount per box?
I've been just wondering how many Wumpa fruits there are per box in Crash Team Racing Nitro-Fueled.
Sometimes I get nine from a single box, and sometimes I get only four.
Is it specific? Or does the game just randomly pick a number from 4 to 9?

Bounce Crates are a type of crate that give Crash ten Wumpa Fruit, and award less than ten Wumpa Fruit in the racing games.

In Nitro-Fueled, 4 to 9 Wumpa Fruit will be awarded based on luck.

Source, Crash Bandicoot fandom.
